Does an array of Peltier module need a diode between each module?
I have a bunch of Peltier module that I wish to connect in series/parallel and use them as a thermopile generator. However I was wondering if its necessary to attach a diode between each module to prevent one thermopile module from "powering" the adjacent module. Is this a valid concern? or can I directly connect the modules together w/o diodes?

between each module ... between a module and what? ... do you mean in series with each module?

Please draw a circuit diagram showing how you want to connect them. Mark where the diodes might go. Also this question should probably be on EE stack exchange.
